# the gathering of several coordinates isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to gather several coordinates from a database and draw them to a map with the markers. The gathering is made using the current position and a radius, thus the coordinates received are those that are within the radius. Here is my code:

```
<fieldset id="geoSection">
   <form id="geoForm" method="post" action="">
      Radius <input type="text" id="radius-input" name="radius" />
      <button id="geo-button" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>
</fieldset>

$('#geo-button:submit').on('click', function() {
     var radiusInput = $('#radius-input').val();
     var numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;

     if(radiusInput === ''){
        alert("Enter a numeric value");
        return false;
     } else if(!numberRegex.test(radiusInput)) {
        alert('Enter a numeric value');
        return false;
     } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        function showPosition(position){
             latCenter = position.coords.latitude;
             lngCenter = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
          url: 'allCoordinatesFromRadius.php',
          data: 'lat=' + latCenter + "&lng=" + lngCenter + "&radius=" + radiusInput,
          cache: 'false',
          dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
          success: function(data) 
          {
             updateMarkers(data);
          }
        });
        return false; 
    }
});

            function removeAllMarkers(){
                for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }

                markers = [];
            }

            function updateMarkers(dataMarkers){
                removeAllMarkers();

                if(clusterer){
                    clusterer.clearMarkers();   
                }

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for (i = 0; i < dataMarkers.length; i++){

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers[i].latitude, dataMarkers[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent("<b>" + dataMarkers[i].name + "</b>" + "<br/> " 
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].street + "<br/> " 
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].code + " " + "<br/> "
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].city + " " + "<br/> "  
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].country);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));

                    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers[i].latitude, dataMarkers[i].longitude));

                    markers.push(marker);
                  }

                  // Fit these bounds to the map
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);

                  clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            }
```

The problem is that the gathering and the drawing of the data works only after the second time  I click the button, namely when I refresh the page, I enter the radius and then I click the button the map doesn't change, but whe I reclick the button it all works. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it happens something strange in the browser.

Comment: I would say maybe try wrapping it in `$(document).ready()` function and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the javascript is already wrap into `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It could be that `latCenter` and `lngCenter` are not available when `ajax` call is started. Try with `ajax` call inside `showPosition` function.

Comment: It doesn't refresh the map if I call the `ajax` inside the `showPosition`